# OAuth call for a request token yields a 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, flickr

I am having an incredibly difficult time getting the OAuth gem working correctly for the Flickr API. I'm trying to generate a request token using this code:

```
user_oauth = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, :site => "https://secure.flickr.com/services")
request_token = user_oauth.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback_url)
```

Whenever I run this code it throws an exception "OAuth::Unauthorized (404 Not Found)" on the call to .get_request_token.

I got my end point from: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.overview.html

My OAuth gem is using the default request_token path, which should work with Flickr according to: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html#request_token I also tried using the endpoint that this link uses (http://www.flickr.com/services)

When I call .request_token_url on my OAuth::Consumer object, it returns "https://secure.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token", which I can access in my browser. Thinking that the flickr API might only work with GET requests, I changed the OAuth method to GET and it still didn't work.

I've used this exact same code on different APIs before and it worked, so I'm not really sure what to do at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the URL that you're passing as your callback_url? From what I've seen you don't need to specify it, but maybe that URL is the one with the 404.

Comment: I'm using a route in my app. I know the callback works because I've used the exact same callback url with other APIs and it worked. Also, the 404 is being generated on the call to .get_request_token, not when I'm being redirected back after authorizing the apps.

Comment: Flickr, like all Yahoo services, require you to give an http or https callback url, without which it won't let you get a request token. Also, Yahoo error responses are pretty weird and you might actually be getting 404 for this reason.

Comment: I didn't have a callback URL set on my Flickr app page, but I just tried setting it and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Request_token_url method returns right url, but I watch on true requested url by wireshark and there was www.flickr.com/oauth/request_token.. So it needs to move /services path from :site option into paths options.

This code works for me, now:

```
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, secret, 
            :site               => "http://www.flickr.com", 
            :request_token_path => '/services/oauth/request_token', 
            :authorize_path     => '/services/oauth/authorize',
            :access_token_path  => '/services/oauth/access_token')
    request_token = consumer.get_request_token
```

Comment: Splitting up the :site and :authorize_path solved my problem when connecting to Intuit's IPP interface also.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but my callback url was "oob" which they say to use if you don't have access to a browser. Anyway I took the quotes off the oob and it works now.